# What to use? delegate, event, or Func<T>?

Tags: c#, events, lambda, delegates

I want to provide objects within a class library the ability to “output” messages without worrying about how it is being output. The class library could be used in a console app, a WinForm or WPF windows application, or a web page.

I’d originally decided that I would use a delegate to handle this. I implemented this using classes but the compiler did not like the delegate when I attempted to put the delegate into an interface that each of these objects inherent from.

I found that I could move the delegate out of the interface and then was able to compile but I'm not sure that this accomplishes what I am trying to do.. It also seems like a kludge so I wanted to ask if any of you have different ideas to accomplish this…

The Interface:

```
namespace Test
{
  using System;
  using System.Xml.Linq;

  public interface IAction
  {
    DisplayMessageDelegate DisplayMessage(string message);
    void Execute();
    XElement Serialize(XName elementName);
  }

  public delegate void DisplayMessageDelegate(string message);
}
```

From there, I'm not sure how to implement this behavior: *(BTW, I know that this code will not compile...)*

```
public class ActionClass1 : IAction
{
  // Other methods not shown...
  void Execute()
  {
    if (this.DisplayMessage != null)
    {
      this.DisplayMessage(“Hello”);
    }
  }
}

public class ConsoleClass
{
  ActionClass1 class1 = new ActionClass1();
  class1.DisplayMessage = { x =>  Console.WriteLine(x); };
}

public class WinFormClass
{
  ActionClass1 class1 = new ActionClass1();
  Class1.DisplayMessage = {x => DisplayTextBox.Text = x; };
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the ability to hook up multiple delegates to respond to a single call to `Execute`, I would definitely use an `event`.  If you only want a single action to be hooked up, use an `Action` or a `Func` delegate.

For your example, one of the [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegates should work.  In your case, it would be `Action<string>` since your delegate takes a string argument.  An `Action` is simply a delegate that takes zero or more arguments and returns void.  It appears that you aren't returning anything, so that's why I'm suggesting `Action`.

You only want to use a [`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) if your delegate needs to return something.  The difference between `Func` and `Action` is that `Func` delegates have a return type, and `Action` delegates do not.  Either of these delegates have generic versions that can take up to 16 or so arguments.

If you need more than 16 arguments on a delegate you might want to reconsider the design :)

Comment: It should be mentioned that if you need anything more complicated than such as params, ref/out... Action/Func wont work. Also another 'nicety' is that you can Name the parameters appropriately (intellisense). That being said i also would use Action<string>.

Answer (score 7):

You could do this using `Action<string>`.

You would not want to use `Func<T>`, as this is defining a delegate that takes no arguments but returns a single value of type T.  `Action<T>`, on the other hand, is a delegate that takes a single argument of type T.

I would suggest trying:

```
public interface IAction
{
    Action<string> DisplayMessage { get; set; }

    void Execute();
    XElement Serialize(XName elementName);
}
```

Once you implemented this interface (completely), you could use it via:

```
public class ConsoleClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ActionClass1 class1 = new ActionClass1();
        class1.DisplayMessage = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class ConsoleClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ActionClass1 class1 = new ActionClass1();
        class1.DisplayMessage = this.Print;
    }

    private void Print(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

You could do the same thing with events, however, I would question this.  Your API is describing an action that should occur, not an event that is happening which you are responding to - and as such, I would not recommend an event.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface definition is wrong. You would need to specify it like so:

```
namespace Test
{
  using System;
  using System.Xml.Linq;

  public interface IAction
  {
    DisplayMessageDelegate DisplayMessage { get; set; };
    void Execute();
    XElement Serialize(XName elementName);
  }

  public delegate void DisplayMessageDelegate(string message);
}
```

and then implement the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
DisplayMessageDelegate DisplayMessage(string message);
```

you describe method that accepts string and returns DisplayMessageDelegate.
Use

```
 event DisplayMessageDelegate DisplayMessage;
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would have though that you would be best off having an abstract base class that defined an abstract method called `DisplayMessage` and then extending that base class by deriving from it to alter the behaviour of the way messages are displayed.

Comment: I did consider that... I left out the fact (in an attempt to simplify the problem) that these derived classes would be in a List<IAction> collection where I would do a ForEach loop to execute the Execute method for each item, setting up the "DisplayMessage" based on the type of application I running at the time...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
DisplayMessageDelegate DisplayMessage(string message);
```

Do:

```
event Action<string> DisplayMessage;
```

Then use the DisplayMessage per normal, events are delegates.